# How can I store my JWT Token in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

userAction.js -> Frontend, Action

```
export const login = (userID, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });
       
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/authenticate/";
        const config = {
          auth: {
            username: userID,
            password,

          },
        };
    
        const data = {};
        const response = await axios.post(
            url, 
            data, 
            config,
            
        )

        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: config});
        
 
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // Login succeeded
          const token = response.data.token;
          console.log("TOKEN\n" + token);
          config.token = response.data.token;
          console.log(response.data.token);
          
        }
        
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(config) );
    }
```

My login function in REST Server :

```
exports.login = async (req,res) =>{

  const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';
  const [userID, password] = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString().split(':');
  const user = await User.findOne({ userID: userID });
  if(!user) return res.status(400).send('User not found');
  const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Incorrect Password');

  //const token = generateToken(user.userID);
  let payload = {
    userID: user.userID
  }
  const token = generateToken(userID);
  
  res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).json(user);
  
  return token;
}
```

I generate my token this way :

```
const generateToken = (_id) => {
  console.log('Signing token for ID ', _id);
  console.log('Secret key is ', process.env.JWT_KEY);
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id}, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });
  console.log('Signed token: ', token);
  return token;
};
```

I try to store my token in my "userInfo" State .. but only username and password is displayed not token ..It works before .. but I don´t know why it´s not working anymore ^^ I´m completely at a loss

I hope someone sees the error

my Console gives me the detail:

```
TOKEN 
undefined
```

Comment: What if you log `response.data`?

Comment: Wait I will try @Leau and edit the log in to my answer

Comment: @Leau the complete user is displayed in console but without token

Comment: Can you show the code where you add token to the response?

Comment: The problem is the response does not have a property `token`. You are returning `user` in the JSON response. Did you intend to return both the user data AND the token in the API response? As in, whats the point of your `return token` if you are doing `res.header().json(user)`?

Comment: You mean in register function ? @Leau otherwise I didn´t understand the question .. I think I do not add the token to response

Comment: I try it now .. wait please @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: You are on the front-end trying to access `response.data.token;`. The API returns `user` as the API payload. `token` won't exist unless it's in the `res.json()` portion right?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky So instead of user I have to res.json(token) ?

Comment: What do YOU want to return from the API request? Do you only want the token? Do you want both the token and user?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky wait now my console show me the token in response.data :)

Comment: I think the token would be nice first .. but If I want to return both how Can I do it ?

Comment: I created an answer showing how to return both

Comment: Don't put jwt in localstorage. This is commonly known.

Comment: @html_programmer it´s only for own project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting `response.data` to be an object. In that case update your API handler to return property `token` in an object:

```js
exports.login = async (req,res) =>{

  const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';
  const [userID, password] = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString().split(':');
  const user = await User.findOne({ userID: userID });
  if(!user) return res.status(400).send('User not found');
  const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Incorrect Password');

  //const token = generateToken(user.userID);
  let payload = {
    userID: user.userID
  }
  const token = generateToken(userID);
  
  return res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).json({ user, token });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!